# How can I create a plot like this in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot the ranges of different cellular base stations in MATLAB, like this:

[image: sample plot]

But I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of how you can create a plot like this. Note that I created sample data for the plot by randomly generating the positions of cellular base stations using [uniformly distributed pseudorandom numbers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rand.html):

```
%# Initializations:
minRange = 0;       %# Lower x and y range
maxRange = 3.5;     %# Upper x and y range
resolution = 1000;  %# The number of data points on the x and y axes
cellRange = linspace(minRange, maxRange, resolution);
[x, y] = meshgrid(cellRange);   %# Create grids of x and y coordinates
cellCoverage = zeros(size(x));  %# Initialize the image matrix to zero

%# Create the sample image data:
numBases = 200;
cellRadius = 0.75;
for iBase = 1:numBases
    point = rand(1,2).*(maxRange - minRange) + minRange;
    index = ((x - point(1)).^2 + (y - point(2)).^2) <= cellRadius^2;
    cellCoverage(index) = cellCoverage(index) + 1;
end

%# Create the plot:
imagesc(cellRange, cellRange, cellCoverage);  %# Scaled plot of image data
axis equal;  %# Make tick marks on each axis equal
set(gca, 'XLim', [minRange maxRange], ...  %# Set the x axis limit
         'YLim', [minRange maxRange], ...  %# Set the y axis limit
         'YDir', 'normal');                %# Flip the y axis direction
xlabel('X-distance (km)');  %# Add an x axis label
ylabel('Y-distance (km)');  %# Add a y axis label
colormap(jet);              %# Set the colormap
colorbar;                   %# Display the color bar
```

And here's the resulting plot:

[image]

Note also that the data in the image matrix `cellCoverage` contains no noise and has no smoothing applied, which is why the edges appear sharper than the original image in the post (which I'm guessing is generated from *real* data, not "fake" sample data like I used here).

Answer (score 0):

Use "image"

image(x),colormap(hsv) <- where x is a matrix of cellular intensities(x,y)

Comment: To clarify, I believe `x` must be a 2D matrix of values between `0` and `1`. But `doc image`, `doc colormap` know more about that than I do.

Comment: then rescale values to 0 to 255 and do hsv(255)

Comment: The figure in question done with `imagesc` function (auto scaling) and `jet` colormap.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the coordinate of each station then create a circle polygon around it (with a given radius), then convert this polygon into a grid. Then you sum up these grids (matrices) on top of each other. For speed, instead of using polygons you can also define which cells will be covered by a station, like all cells within 5 rows or columns of a station get the value. 
You can also apply a 2D Gaussian filter to your matrix, where only the cells containing a station have a value of 1. The bandwidth of your Gaussian kernel will be your coverage radius (range). http://www.mathworks.ch/help/toolbox/images/ref/fspecial.html